# jquery resources for a completely javascript ignorant

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to start learning jquery, but I'm definitely a newbie even in plain javascript: any suggestion to get started the proper way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/07/great-ways-to-learn-jquery

Answer (score 2):

A great reference that I use a lot:

http://www.visualjquery.com

Comment: very nice, +1, but I would like to see something helping user to organize the code too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jQuery "book" by Rebecca Murphey with help from James Padolsey, Paul Irish that is really good: 
http://jqfundamentals.com/book/book.html